# Word for a thing with positive and negative consequences

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, idioms

What word can I use for a thing with positive and negative consequences? For example, taking a cab rather than driving has its advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an idiom that conveys the meaning of the French “mi figue mi raisin”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41472/is-there-an-idiom-that-conveys-the-meaning-of-the-french-mi-figue-mi-raisin)

Comment: Also see [Proverb or expression for a situation with two choices both leading to a different kind of trouble](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38243),

Comment: http://www.newyorker.com/cartoons/a18915

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure of a single word. You might use the phrase [**double-edged sword**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus/british/sword#a-double-edged-two-edged-sword_1), e.g.

> Taking a cab is a double-edged sword. You don't have to worry about parking, but it is more expensive.

Answer (score 4):

For intermingled positive and negative emotions, I would use *bittersweet*.  Clearly though, the phrase "taking a cab is bittersweet" doesn't really hit the mark, unless you're discussing the conflict of leaving vs going.  The best I can come up with is "taking a cab rather than driving has *mixed/conflicting/divergent* consequences."  I'll think more though, those still feel off the mark to me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're saying that two things have the same chances they will turn out well, or both are equally appealing choices, you can call it a **toss-up**.

> "Should we take a cab or drive?"
>
> "A cab sounds expensive, but I'm really tired. It's a toss-up."

Answer (score 3):

*[Mixed bag](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20bag)*:

> one having both positive and negative qualities or aspects

Also spelled *[mixed-bag](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mixed-bag)*, to meet the single word criterion.

Comment: I like both mix-bag and toss-up for declaring that something has positive and negative consequences. Any idea of a single word to use to refer to the actual consequences (the things in the mixed-bag)?

Answer (score -1):

Dichotomy - when presented with the choices

Merriam-Webster defines [Dichotomy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomy) as

> something with seemingly contradictory qualities
>   it's a dichotomy, this opulent Ritz-style luxury in a place that fronts on a

So in the current example, it could be used such as

> Driving is a dichotomy with increased comfort but long term disadvantages.